# Connect-Exchange CertificatePath in Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I'm trying to understand how to add the parameter *-CertificateFilePath* in a Powershell Azure Function. Locally you just add the location of the path *c:\locationpath*.

But when used in a Azure Function, I'm not sure how to add the file path from a Function App that has the cert already in *TLS/SSL settings* where I've uploaded the certificate.

A common way I've seen to do is:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppID $AppId -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint -Organization company.com
```

But that usually has a pop up that ask for an account to select which is why it might be failing in the Function. Also I'm trying to use a certificate.

Another way I've seen is using the AZ Vault, which I didn't want to use if my certificates are already in an app registration and in the Function itself in *TLS/SSL Settings*.

I just want to be able to query Exchange without user credentials with a service I've created. Thank you.

Comment: Does this helpful https://msazure.club/connect-to-azure-ad-from-azure-function-with-powershell-script/ ?

Comment: I will follow this @VenkateshDodda-MT and get back to you. I think I've done all of these steps besides the FTP part with the password, not sure if that will make a difference but I will try. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [venkateshdodda-mt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15968720/venkateshdodda-mt) Suggested try the below steps

1 Generate Certificate and Service Principal

- By credential
- By CertificateThumbprint & ApplicationId
- By AadAccessToken & AccountId

```
# Login to Azure AD PowerShell With Admin Account
Connect-AzureAD

# Create the self signed cert
$currentDate = Get-Date
$endDate  = $currentDate.AddYears(1)
$notAfter  = $endDate.AddYears(1)
$pwd  = "YOUR_PASSWORD"
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName YOUR_DNS -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $notAfter).Thumbprint
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my\$thumb" -FilePath YOUR_PFX_PATH.pfx -Password $pwd

# Load the certificate
$cert  = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("YOUR_PFX_PATH.pfx", $pwd)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())

# Create the Azure Active Directory Application
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "YOUR_APP_NAME" -IdentifierUris "https://YOUR_APP_NAME"
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $application.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "YOUR_PASSWORD" -StartDate $currentDate -EndDate $endDate -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $keyValue

# Create the Service Principal and connect it to the Application
$sp = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $application.AppId

# Give the Service Principal Reader access to the current tenant (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole)
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId 72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47 -RefObjectId $sp.ObjectId

# Get Tenant Detail
$tenant = Get-AzureADTenantDetail

# Now you can login to Azure PowerShell with your Service Principal and Certificate
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenant.ObjectId -ApplicationId  $sp.AppId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb

# Output TenantId, AppId and Thumbprint to use in azure function's script
Write-Host "TenantId: "$tenant.ObjectId
Write-Host "AppId: "$sp.AppId
Write-Host "Thumbprint: "$thumb
```

2  Configure Azure Function to Use Certificate

[image]

3 Copy AzureAD PowerShell Module to Azure Function

4 Write PowerShell Script from Azure Function to Connect to Azure AD

for further information check [Azure functions check with powershell](https://msazure.club/connect-to-azure-ad-from-azure-function-with-powershell-script/)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This one way from the article worked for me.